# What causes MPI_Irecv and MPI_Testall to a fail?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a custom MPI struct that get passed between processes.  Previously I was sending/receiving each struct individually and it was working fine, but the performance bottleneck is MPI, so I am trying to send/recv in chunks (If this doesn't help performance than I can scrap this all together).

Initially I tried sending chunks with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, but apparently there are size limitations for MPI_Send to become non-blocking, so it got locked up.  Now I am switching to a completely non-blocking MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv.  The issue is that the MPI_Testall flag never gets set and the data is never received.

My code:

```
map<int, vector<fvm::F>> borders_recv; // {local rank: [structs...]}
map<int, vector<fvm::F*>> borders_send; // {local rank: [struct pointers...]}


// ... values are filled ...


map<int, vector<fvm::F>> borders_send_buffer; // {local rank: [structs...]}
vector<MPI_Request> reqs;


MPI_Barrier(COMM_ITER);
        
cerr << "transferring " << r << endl;

for(auto& b : borders_send){
    
    // b.first is the rank to send data to
    // b.second is a vector of fvm::F* (Need to copy these structs into an actual struct array for MPI_Isend)
    
    int cc = b.second.size();
    
    // initialize map and vector size
    borders_send_buffer[b.first];
    if(borders_send_buffer[b.first].size() == 0){
        borders_send_buffer[b.first].resize(cc);
    }


    // fill send buffer with correct structs
    for(int i = 0; i < cc; i++){
        borders_send_buffer[b.first][i] = *b.second[i];
    }


    MPI_Isend(borders_send_buffer[b.first].data(), cc, STRUCT_FACE, b.first, b.first, COMM_ITER, &req_b);

    cerr << "sending " << r << " -> " << b.first << " (" << cc << ")" << endl;

}

MPI_Barrier(COMM_ITER);


if(reqs.size() == 0){
    reqs.resize(borders_recv.size());
}
        

int n = 0;
for(auto& b : borders_recv){

     MPI_Irecv(b.second.data(), b.second.size(), STRUCT_FACE, b.first, b.first, COMM_ITER, &reqs[n++]);

     cerr << "recving " << r << " <- " << b.first << " (" << b.second.size() << ")" << endl;
}

int flag = 0;

while(true){
    MPI_Testall(reqs.size(), reqs.data(), &flag, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
    if(flag){
        break;
    }
}

MPI_Barrier(COMM_ITER);
```

The output with 2 ranks:

```
transferring 0
sending 0 -> 1 (673)
recving 0 <- 1 (767)
transferring 1
sending 1 -> 0 (767)
recving 1 <- 0 (673)
```

What would be causing the MPI_Irecv & MPI_Testall to fail?

Comment: are you sure the tags match?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh wow! it's always the little things.  Thank you for noticing.

Comment: note you do not `MPI_Wait(&req_b, ...)` and the request is overwritten if there is more than one `borders_send`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That's good to know.  I'll use a separate MPI_Request for each MPI_Isend